# Вылетает приложение при запуске если "без наушников" и запускается если они присоединены

Tags: java, android-studio, broadcast-receiver, android-toast, headset

Есть BroadCastReceiver позволяющий ловить событие подключения или отключения наушников, и останавливать воспроизведение, если наушники были извлечены:

Сообщение в приложении выводится каждый раз, когда я перехожу в главное активити, будь то подключены наушники или нет, - мне об этом сразу сообщается.

Как сделать так, чтобы это сообщение показывалось только при подключении или отключении наушников? Иначе даже не подключая их, мне выводится сообщение с текстом что **"Наушники отключены"**.

```
 class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
                case 0: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники отключены");{
                    if (HomeActivity.musicSrv.isPng()){
                        HomeActivity.musicSrv.pausePlayer();
                    }
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Наушники отключены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
                case 1: Log.d(TAG, "Наушники подключены");
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Наушники подключены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default: Log.d(TAG, "Неизвестное состояние");
            }


     }
        }
    }
```

**P.S:** Данный способ у меня почему то срабатывает только когда наушники присоединены, в противном случае приложение открывается и сразу вылетает с ошибкой. Стоит присоединить наушники и открыть приложение = оно сразу открывается и нормально работает.

Лог ошибки, при подключении без наушников:

```
05-11 12:29:11.841 25433-25433/com.online.radio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.online.radio, PID: 25433
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG flg=0x40000010 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } bqHint=1 (has extras) } in com.online.radio.activity.HomeActivity$MusicIntentReceiver@66db610
                                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1188)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6724)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.online.radio.service.MusicService.isPng()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.online.radio.activity.HomeActivity$MusicIntentReceiver.onReceive(HomeActivity.java:96)
                                                                              at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1178)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6724) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Изменил весь код на:

```
private boolean headsetConnected = false;
public class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)){
                if (headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 0){
                    headsetConnected = false;
                    if (HomeActivity.musicSrv.isPng()){
                        HomeActivity.musicSrv.pausePlayer();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Наушники отключены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (!headsetConnected && intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1){
                    headsetConnected = true;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Наушники подключены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот ресивер срабатывает сразу при регистрации дабы оповестить Вас о текущем состоянии наушников, но существует ли сервис на этот момент? Второе. Вы регистрируете в onResume активности - поэтому и срабатывает при переходе на неё да и вообще работает только когда она открыта. Перенос ресивера и его регистрации в сервис Вас избавит от проблем. Только на вывод тостов из сервиса потребуется пермишн.

Comment: Ничего не стал переносить, а просто изменил код, на тот, который добавил в главном посте. На сколько это решение правильное? (Теперь и сообщение не выводится каждый раз при переходе между активностями, и естественно приложение не вылетает с ошибкой, если я захожу  в него без наушников, как раньше))

Comment: из жизненного цикла, имею только     

    public void onResume() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

в других ничего не писал., но и работает зато на всех активностях. А по поводу того запущен сервис или нет, это вы действительно правы. Как я понял, в написанном коде , я пытался остановить воспроизведение там, где его еще и не было даже и ошибку в логах получал, т.к состояние у него было "null" ... ну  я как то так понял это.

Comment: так же у меня почему то всё исправно работает , вне зависимости , указал ли я  в манифесте 
<receiver
            android:name=".activity.HomeActivity$MusicIntentReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

или нет..

Comment: Без unregister при каждом переходе в активность добавляется еще один ресивер - пять раз свернул-развернул - пять ресиверов и все выводят тосты, дёргают сервис и держат в памяти активность или даже её дубликаты (про утечку слышали)

Comment: то есть нужно обязательно дописать в onDestroy ?

Comment: Нужно использовать парные - resume/pause, create/destroy

Comment: но если я допишу в onPause , тогда код будет работать в одной активности, я правильно понимаю? И при извлечении наушников, если пользователь находился в другой активности, у него ничего не произойдет и музыка продолжит играть))

Comment: в логах смотрел, при множественном перемещениям по активностям что происходит, и не уходит ли свободная память. Память как бы уходит, но когда её становится мало, то в логах вижу: I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 168664(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 115(6MB) LOS objects, 11% free, 118MB/134MB, paused 7.577ms total 117.590ms

Comment: и дальше автоматически, она освобождается., судя по монитору., но ничего сверхъестественного не происходит, всё работает дальше как положено.